# What's happened to Games for Windows Live? I can't open Dark Souls or GFWL at all!

Tags: dark-souls, games-for-windows-live

#### This may be two separate issues into the one question... Unless the same issues caused both things.

For some reason, I'm unable to connect to GFWL. Has the servers been shut off or anything?  Every time I open the GFWL application, it always gives this:

[image: "Connection Error" ... No connection to LIVE service.]

With everything installed, when I attempt to open Dark Souls (via Steam), it crashes.
*If you need a crash log, please tell me how to get one.*
All it does is open, black screen for barely a second, and then crash.

[image: DARK SOULS has stopped responding. -_-]

---

In case: System specs

Operating System: Windows 8.1 Home Premium, 64-bit
RAM: 4GB
Processor: Intel i5 Processor, with Intel Graphics.
Internet Connection: Yes - Otherwise how would I post this question?
*Is it (Dark Souls and GFWL) allowed through the firewall? **Yes.***

---

If you need something to answer (questions for guidelines), here's the two you should address:

- What has happened to GFWL? Has it shut down?
- Is there any way I can log in offline? (I've logged in before on this computer)

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere that they were completely shutting down GFWL but they were going to support dark souls afterwards

Comment: @freebol96, are you talking about http://store.steampowered.com/news/externalpost/steam_community_announcements/521615416996183174?

Comment: yes This is the exact post i was talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GFWL has not shut down (as of writing this post) — I logged in just now and checked with Dark Souls myself. I use Windows 8.1 64-bit as well and I had to run it in **compatibility mode** or it would crash on launch (set compatibility to **Windows 8, run as administrator** on DARKSOULS.exe). Your GFWL being unable to connect could mean it's out of date or, as the error message suggests, there's just something stopping your connection.

If I refuse to login to GFWL when prompted right before the splash screens, I can play offline just fine. That should work even if you haven't signed in before, though I'm not sure if saving will be available.

Comment: GFWL **is** going away, though.

Comment: @Powerlord it is, but has not.

Comment: Still doesn't explain how I can't log into offline mode though. The splash screen doesn't even appear. Dark Souls crash before it gets to it.

Comment: @aytimothy the compatibility mode was what fixed the crash before splash screen for me, so I don't know...